# flowplayer: fullscreen not working

Tags: javascript, flash, fullscreen, flowplayer

I have a button under my player which I want to use to trigger the full screen by using the following code:

```
$f().toggleFullscreen()
```

I tried in `Chrome`, `IE10` and `Firefox` and it doesn't work. I can get full screen only by double click on the movie or by using the button from the controls plugin.

Errors from these browsers:

- Firefox: `uncaught exception: Error in Actionscript. Use a try/catch
  block to find error.`
- Chrome: `Error calling method on NPObject.`
- IE10: `Could not complete the operation due to error 8070000c.`

I tried looking for the error code by `Google`, but all links related to `flowplayer` direct me to `flowplayer` forum, but I got there `504 Gateway Time-out` and there is no copy of the page in the `Google`cache.

I have a little configuration for the player, but this problem occurs even in the simplest case:

```
 <a
                href="http://local/app/test.flv"
                style="display: block; width: 520px; height: 330px"
                id="player"></a>
//...
     flowplayer("player", "../../App_Common/FlowPlayer/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf");
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are getting these errors because the browser does not support it.  If you look in flowplayer docs under [Methods](http://flowplayer.org/docs/api.html#methods) There is a `fullscreen()` method.  This states

> Note: Many browsers allow this method to work only from events which are triggered by user interaction, like "click", and not for example from player events like "ready" which happen at moments undetermined by the user.

Also, it looks like you are using the older flash version of flowplayer.  In their docs for fullscreen it also states that it will only work when interacting with the player rather than from a button.

[flowplayer flash - toggleFullscreen](http://flash.flowplayer.org/demos/events/toggle-fullscreen.html)